# Kendo Grid with custom popup editor using MultiSelect - can't get selected items in model

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

So the title pretty much says it all. I'm trying to incorporate the new MultiSelect widget into a Grid's custom popup editor template.

I'm using the Data Attribute Initialization method and reading the dropdown options from a remote dataSource. This is all working okay, but I can't get the values of the selected items into the model.

When I save the row, an array of data is sent to the server representing the first data item selected in the MultiSelect, rather than a comma-separated list of selected values.

Any ideas how I can get the MultiSelect value (list/array of selected values) into the grid model?

Thanks

Edit: I've now used a workaround, but I'd be interested to know if there's a 'proper way' to use MultiSelects with Grids.

The workaround is to add something like this to the Grid's configuration:

```
save: function(e) { 
    e.model.items = $('#select_items').data("kendoMultiSelect").value();
}
```

This is the relevant part of the popup editor template:

```
<input name="select_items" id="select_items" data-value-field="id" 
data-text-field="description" data-source="itemsDataSource" 
data-role="multiselect" data-auto-bind="false" data-item-template="itemList">
```

I've not got `select_items` in the model definition: I'm using the workaround above to copy the MultiSelect's value to `items` which is in the model. This seems to work, I just don't know why it is necessary.

Comment: Can you include your editor code in your OP? It seems to me that the problem is with the editor and the multiselect definition not updating the model.

Comment: Just had a thought... could it be anything to do with the model definition? What should the field type be for a MultiSelect -- I'm using `string` is that right?

Comment: Internally it is an array of strings but when displayed (the input) is a serialization of the array and then a string. You can use map in transport.create / transport.update for converting it to whatever you need in the server (you might also do it in parameterMap (check DataSource documentation)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I've tried to see what's passed to the model on save by simply adding: `console.dir(e.model.items)` into the Grid's `save` function. It just displays `[object Object]` with no properties. I've tried adding `data.items = kendo.stringify(data.items);` into the transport.update, but that doesn't work either -- just returns `"[object Object]"`. Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: What would you prefer to send to the server: a string of options separated by comma or an array of options?

Comment: Hi. To be honest, I could deal with either of those, but an array of options would probably be more useful.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For using `MultiSelect` in Grids there are a couple o questions to consider:

1. Grid editors only support as type for columns `string`, `boolean`, `number` and `date`. Since you will want to save an array of ... let's say `string` you will have to work around this.
2. Since you are receiving an array of values from the server, you will have to use a `template` for serializing it to a `string` in order to display values received from the server.
3. KendoUI is not able of guessing that you want to use a MultiSelect as input so you have to provide and `editor` function.

Let's work around all these questions:

To solve the question of `array` of `string` the simplest solution is not saying anything to KendoUI about what is receiving.

For the `template`, I'm going to be using the JavaScript `join` method to pull all the values together separated by a ", ". Something like:

```
{ field: "Cities", template: "#= Cities.join(', ') #" }
```

Finally for the editor, I use:

```
{ field: "Cities", template: "#= Cities.join(', ') #", editor : citiesEditor }

function citiesEditor(container, options) {
    $("<select multiple='multiple' data-bind='value : Cities'/>").appendTo(container).kendoMultiSelect({
        dataSource: citiesDS
    });
}
```

Where in my case `citiesDS` is just an `array` of `string` with the name of valid Cities.

```
var citiesDS = [
    "Boston", "Kirkland", "London", "New York", "Philadelphia", "Redmond", "Seattle", "Tacoma"
];
```

When you update (save), it will send to the host an `array` of strings with the cities introduced in `Cities` field.

Example: here http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/Q2w7z/

Comment: Thanks a bunch. Will use this.