# Kendo Grid with MultiSelect in EditPop, Sending [Object Object] to the server on Save

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, mvc-editor-templates, kendo-multiselect

I am using `Kendo MultiSelect` as `UIHint` for one the columns in my `Kendo Grid`. And I am trying to send selected values of the multiSelect in comma separated string to the server in the databound item.

the entity having the `UIHint` is like this:

```
public class Test 
{
    [UIHint("Labels")]
    public string Labels { get; set; }
    //other properies
}
```

I've a kendo Grid of type `Test` i.e.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Test>().Name("gridMain").Colum...
```

`UIHint` `Labels.cshtml` is like this:

```
@(Html.Kendo().MultiSelect().Name("Labels") 
    .DataValueField("Id") 
    .DataTextField("Name") 
    .DataSource(s =>
    {
        s.Read(read => read.Action("Labels_Read", "Library"))
    })
)
```

When I Add/Edit an item, and click on Save, I always receive `[Object Object]` value in the Labels property on the server side which is like :

```
public ActionResult Test_Save(Test obj)
{
   //obj.Labels is always having "[Object Object]" value

   // rest of the logic 
}
```

I've gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17575578/kendo-grid-with-custom-popup-editor-using-multiselect-cant-get-selected-items) and few others, even tried to intercept the request on `RequestStart` and modify the added/edited `item .Labels` value explicitly, still, my obj( at server) receives `[Object Object]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following setting should sort you out, issue is described [here](http://www.kendoui.com/forums/kendo-ui-web/dropdownlist/dropdownlist-with-mvvm-binding-to-the-data-value-field-and-not-the-object.aspx):

```
 data-value-primitive="true"
```

Selected value from your multiselect is keyvalue pair of text and id, that is source of the `[Object Object]`. You can also fix this and any other param related issues in [parameterMap](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#configuration-transport.parameterMap)